# Can you disable multiline on Telerik RadEditor?

Tags: user-interface, telerik

Is it possible to make a Telerik RadEditor single-line entry only?

For example, in an ASP TextBox there is the Multiline attribute

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, just figured it out...

It's a bit weird, but there is an attribute for NewLineBr in the RadEditor.

```
<telerik:RadEditor NewLineBr="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

Single line editing not possible with the RadEditor. It always uses an iframe element for the content area where the asp:textbox uses a textarea/input. Even if you make the height of the iframe be a single line, when the user presses Enter, they will get a new line. If you need a single line input from Telerik, then you can try using the [RadInput control](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/input/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx).